# ASP.NET allow anonymous access to OData $metadata when site has global AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2, odata-v4

I have an ASP.NET OData site that has the following in the WebApiConfig file:

```
config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute())
```

This forces all callers to authenticate before calling any of the controllers.
Unfortunately, this also forces user authentication to access the "$metadata" url.
I need to globally force authentication for all controller access while also allowing anonymous access the the "$metadata" url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom filter that derives from `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the `IsAuthorized` method as follows:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath == "/$metadata" ||
            actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath == "/%24metadata")
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Register the filter:

```
config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizationFilter());
```

Comment: It works! If you add a route prefix in  Odata config, then you should modify the absolute path accordingly. Example:  `if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath == "/Odata/$metadata")`

Answer (score 6):

I realize this question has already been answered, but I have a couple concerns with the accepted answer:

- Assumes the metadata endpoint will not change
- Requires updating the code if an endpoint is added/moved
- Does not handle the root endpoint (without /$meatdata)

I agree with creating your own `AuthorizeAttribute`, but I would implement the method a little differently.

```
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller is System.Web.OData.MetadataController)
            return true;

        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
```

My solution simply checks to see if the controller being accessed is OData's MetadataController. If it is, allow anyone access, otherwise, go through the normal authorization checks.

Comment: This is a great solution and does not require me to look at the url for specific keywords like metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add one more option.  If you replace the default Web API dependency resolver (HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = YourIDependencyResolver) you can intercept the request for the metadata controller (ODataMetadataController or MetadataController, depending on the version of the OData library) and replace it with your own implementation,  like below:

```
[AllowAnonymous, OverrideAuthorization]
public class AnonymousODataMetadataController : ODataMetadataController
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        // You must replace the controller descriptor because it appears
        // that the AuthorizeAttribute is pulled from the 
        // controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType (which 
        // is the original type) instead of from controlContext.Controller
        // (which is the type we injected).
        controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor
        {
            Configuration = controllerContext.Configuration,
            ControllerName = GetType().Name,
            ControllerType = GetType()
        };

        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    }
}
```

See [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) for info about the Web API dependency injection system.