# ASP.NET.Core allow anonymous access to OData $metadata when RequireAuthenticatedUser() is set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I have an **`ASP.NET Core 2.1`** site that has the following in the `WebApiConfig` file:

```
 services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                // Force authorization for all controllers
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
```

This forces all callers to authenticate before calling any of the controllers.
Unfortunately, this also forces user authentication to access the OData "$metadata" URL.

Is there a way to allow anonymous access to the metadata page?

Note: this is the same question as below (but for .NET Core)

[ASP.NET allow anonymous access to OData $metadata when site has global AuthorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894875/asp-net-allow-anonymous-access-to-odata-metadata-when-site-has-global-authorize)

Comment: Not the best way, but you could do something like this: https://joonasw.net/view/apply-authz-by-default. Basically, you build something that will find your controllers by convention, make them secure by adding the AuthorizeFilter to them. This would avoid adding it to the OData ones. So I think it would work. Another thing I can think of are Filters.. but I'd rather not go that way I think.

Comment: Thanks @jpgrassi, that might work for the odata controllers I have defined, but the convention doesn't seem to capture $metadata controller which is registered by Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.AddOData() I believe.

Comment: Yeah but the idea it is for it not to catch it, thus leaving it open(unauthenticated)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear since I typed this in my mobile:  You would remove the global `config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));` meaning ALL your controllers (including the ones added by the NuGet package) would be publicly accessible. To avoid having to add `Authorize` manually to all of * your controllers*, you create this "auto-adding" convention. The goal is that all the controllers you create, are protected but the ones added by the OData NuGet package aren't. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

With the following implementation you can have anonymous access to OData $metadata and keep authentication for any other controllers:
(A controller with the name "metadata" will be automatically generated if you previously set up OData service correctly - this is not included here).

1.) Add following class

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
    public class AuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention : 
    IControllerModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
        {
            if (!controller.ControllerName.Contains("Metadata"))
            {
                controller.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("defaultPolicy"));
            }
        }
     }
```

2.) In the ConfigureServices method of the StartUp class remove your existing addMvc method and add the following:

```
      services.AddAuthorization(o =>
            {
                o.AddPolicy("defaultPolicy", b =>
                {
                    b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                });
            });

       services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                o.Conventions.Add(new AuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention());
            })
```